# How can I get the element that was right-clicked via a Google Chrome context menu?

Tags: google-chrome, contextmenu, element

I am creating a context menu item in Google chrome like so:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
 "title":"My Context Menu Item", 
 "contexts":["editable"], 
 "onclick": onClick
});
```

The `onClick` callback receives two arguments: an `OnClickInfo` object and a tab object.  Neither object appears to contain a reference to the DOM element that was right-clicked when invoking the context menu.  I have `console.logged` both of these objects but don't see any reference to the targeted element anywhere.

The desired outcome:

- user right-clicks an editable element
- user clicks my context menu item
- within the `onClick` callback, have my extension search for a parent 'form' element relative to the targeted right-click element

As it stands right now, it doesn't look like Chrome offers any reference to the targeted element.  Has anyone found a way around this limitation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must inject a content script in each page and listen for `mousedown` event and log the last clicked element. Then, when a context menu callback is called you must `sendRequest` to the tab to get the info about that last clicked element.

Comment: Log with console.log? sendRequest? Do you mean an AJAX call?

Comment: Sophivorus, I think by logging Scott means to store in memory, in a variable for instance, a reference to the element or some other kind of reference to be able to retrieve the element later.

Comment: This answer gives a more thorough explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703697/how-to-retrieve-the-element-where-a-contextmenu-has-been-executed

TLDR; in your content script you listen for "contextmenu" events and when they occur you assign the clicked element to a variable.

Then in your service worker script you can send a message to the tab and ask for the clicked element.