# HTML5 contextmenu - Access originally clicked element when menu item is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, contextmenu

I'm experimenting with the HTML5 contextmenu item in the latest version of Firefox (only browser that currently supports it). When I click on a menu item from the context menu how can I access the original element that was clicked when the menu was spawned?

The use case would be displaying a list of items and you want the user to perform an action on a particular item. Once the action is clicked from the menu you need a way to determine what element in the list was originally clicked on to spawn the menu.

[Here is a JSFiddle (use Firefox to test)](http://jsfiddle.net/rawberg/GALmp/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just save it somewhere like `this.cte = arguments[0];` then retrieve it later `document.getElementById('testitem').cte`

http://jsfiddle.net/GALmp/4/

Comment: yeah that approach is the one I have working now but I was hoping for a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same or very similar situation.  I have a context menu bound to a `<tr>` in the header of a table.  When the user clicks a certain item in the contextmenu, inside the click event handler I needed to determine which `<th>` element the mouse pointer was over when a `<menuitem>` element was clicked.

Solution: document.activeElement refers to exactly the element I need.  Thanks to:

- [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703697/how-to-retrieve-the-element-where-a-contextmenu-has-been-executed?rq=1)
- [comment 7 on the related google chrome issue thread](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=39507#c7).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It correctly answers the question asked, and help to solve a problem of mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery contextMenu plug-in, which is browser independent. In particular, the following example:
http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo/on-dom-element.html
shows how to identify the triggering DOM element.

Comment: No you can’t. This is not the HTML5 Context Menu at all. Among other things it bypasses the existing context menu, so you lose the original items.

Answer (score -1):

The `this` keyword works as in any event.

Comment: And it is completely useless as it points to the `<menuitem>` and not the item with the `contextmenu` attribute that opened it.