# How can I get the id of the focused textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox

I am creating a Chrome extension and I need to get the id of the selected textbox on the page.
I am using Javascript and jQuery

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert text into selected textbox in JavaScript without ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43966106/how-to-insert-text-into-selected-textbox-in-javascript-without-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can get the `id` using pure `javascript`:-

```
document.activeElement.getAttribute('id')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:focus` pseudo-class selector.
for instance:
`$("input:focus")` will get the focused input.