# Is there a way to get the alt tag of an image from chrome.contextMenu.create

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

How do I get the image alt tag of the selected image, is there a way around this ?

```
function addNewImageFromSelectionRightClickMenu() {
    chrome.contextMenus.removeAll(function() {
        chrome.contextMenus.create({
            title: "Add image to Product",
            contexts:["image"],  // ContextType
            onclick: newImageFromSelection // A callback function
        })
    });
}
```

```
function newImageFromSelection(e) {
    console.log(469, e);
    document
    injectedScriptDispatcher({
        action: "newImageInSelection",
        ...e
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution 1.

The usual advice is to declare a content script that runs in all tabs and listens to `contextmenu` event, saves the clicked event target element, then processes it in onMessage listener ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7704392)).

However, such a content script will be needlessly running 99.99999999% of the time, it also requires broad host permissions which puts such an extension into the extremely slow manual review queue in Chrome Web Store and possibly other extension galleries.

#### Solution 2.

A possibly better approach is to use `activeTab` permission and a dynamically injected content script that retroactively gets the clicked element by looking for image `src` reported to the contextMenus callback.

manifest.json excerpt:

```
"permissions": ["activeTab", "contextMenus"],
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"],
  "persistent": false
}
```

background.js:

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
    code: `(${findElement})(${JSON.stringify(info)})`,
    frameId: info.frameId,
    matchAboutBlank: true,
    runAt: 'document_start',
  }, ([result] = []) => {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      console.error('Error: ' + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    } else {
      console.log('Alt:', result);
    }
  });
});
// this function's code will be executed as a content script in the web page
function findElement({mediaType, srcUrl}) {
  const tagName = mediaType === 'image' ? 'img' : mediaType;
  for (const el of document.querySelectorAll(tagName)) {
    if (el.src === srcUrl) {
      return el.alt;
    }
  }
}
```

This code doesn't try to pierce ShadowDOM which is an exercise for the reader ([example in the wild](https://github.com/tophf/view-image-video-info/blob/master/content/show-info.js#L62)). The shortcomings are a) the inability to pierce a closed ShadowDOM root and b) the possibility of a duplicate image with the same `src` but a different attribute that you want to retrieve (specifically, `alt`).