# Google Chrome Extension - Get DIV and Other Info Near Clicked Element

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My Google Chrome Extension currently retrieves the ImageURL which was right-clicked from the menu, but that's not enough. I also need to do this:

- Get the DIV Element inside which this specific Image was clicked.
- Get some text strings stored inside this DIV, or in sub-DIVs, next
     to the clicked image.

So far I have this, which is working:

**background.js**

```
// Add context menu for Images
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": "Get this Image",
    "contexts": ["image"],
    "onclick" : getInfo
  });

function getInfo(e)
{
    var imgURL = e.srcUrl;

    // Set up an event which Content will receive
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {url: imgURL}, function(response) {
        alert('Response in Background');
      });
});
}
```

**contentscript.js**

```
// Listener for Background Event Sends
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    // print Image Src URL in a custom Content-created place
    divHTML = request.url;
    document.getElementById('infoDiv').innerHTML = divHTML;
  });
```

Where do I do the extra work to analyze the DOM tree and retrieve extra surrounding elements? In the Background or in the Content?

Comment: Have you tried getting the parent of e in background.js? `e.parentElement`

Comment: Yes, added in the background.js function getInfo(e):  var parent = e.parentElement; alert('Parent is:  ' + parent); Result: Parent is: Undefined

Comment: Ah, the object passed in is not a DOM element. You'd have to inject a content script to listen for click events and keep track of the element clicked. This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642603/how-can-i-get-the-element-that-was-right-clicked-via-a-google-chrome-context-men